# jQuery scrollTo() "unrecognized expression"

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error, anchor, scrollto

I tried to use the methode explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/1637380) answer in order to create a simple 3-point-menu that would let the user scroll to the respective sections.

Ended up with this code:

HTML

```
<body>
    <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="navLink" href="#home">HOME</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="navLink" href="#info">INFO</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="navLink" href="#pics">PICS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </nav>

    <section id="home">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </section>

    <section id="info">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </section>

    <section id="pics">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </section>
</body>
```

JS

```
$('a.navLink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this.href);
    if( target.length ) {
        $("html, body").scrollTo(target, { duration: 1000, easing: "linear" });
    }
});
```

Upon clicking any of the three links I end up with:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
http://localhost/meckerHP/#whatevervalueinhref
```

Even tried not using the href attribute at all by using an id for each link instead, which does eliminate the error message but leaves me with dead links.

I can't see any reason whatsoever why the method in the above-linked answer shouldn't be working, so any help is really appreciated.

Comment: [.scrollTo()](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo) is a plugin. You have to include it in your project.

Comment: Indeed, I stumbled upon [this](http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/) manual page and mistook it for an actual jQuery reference page, while in fact the function scrollTo() is part of [this](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plug-in.

Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by changing the line below from:

```
var target = $(this.href);
```

to:

```
var target = $($(this).attr('href'));
```

The problem with your initial line of code is that `this.href` will return the full URL of your anchor, not just the literal value in your `href` in the HTML.  So you can't use that as a jQuery selector because of that. If you instead use `$($(this).attr('href'));`, that basically evaluates to `$("#theHref");` which is what you expected.

Comment: Ah, of course, that makes sense - I somehow presumed using .href would also give me just the value of that attribute. One should always use functions like $.attr() for this sort of thing - stupid me.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Fiddle that should help you: http://jsfiddle.net/Delorian/s0d34qhk/

I extracted out the id by finding the # in the link and referencing that.

I also changed the animation to use the function in the answer you referenced: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/3264286

```
$('a.navLink').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = this.href;
    var target = $(href.substring(href.lastIndexOf('#')));
    if( target.length ) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you - I realized, however, that I confused jQuery's scrollTop() function with scrollTo(), which is part of a dedicated jQuery plug-in. That and me not using the attr() function to access the value of the anchor's href-attribute caused my code to fail.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing the `href` property from the DOM anchor element will give back a full url instead of what is just in the href attribute on the tag. Because of this you are passing the jQuery method a url which is an invalid expression for selectors.

You can use jQuery's attr method to get the actual attribute text

```
var target = $(this).attr("href");
```

DEMO

```js
jQuery("a.navLink").each(function(){
  var property = this.href;
  var attr = jQuery(this).attr("href");
  var prop = jQuery(this).prop("href");
  
  jQuery("#log").append('<div>Property Value: '+property+'</div>');
  jQuery("#log").append('<div>Attribute Value: '+attr+'</div>');
  jQuery("#log").append('<div>Prop Value: '+prop+'</div>');
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="log"></div>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="navLink" href="#home">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="navLink" href="#info">INFO</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="navLink" href="#pics">PICS</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```